# Understanding a transform of 3d plane coordinates to xy plane

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, transformation

I have a series of random movements that can either go +x, +y, +z. 1/3 chance each. After 1000 steps, the average ending point is 333,333,333. Here is many trials for an average. [500 trials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98itt.png) This also forms a plane where each line ends. I wanted to plot these ending points on a xy plane equivalent, where the xy plane origin is 333,333,333. If the x,y ending points are taken directly, I feel it is almost the shadow of the lines ending points projected onto the xy plane. It creates an oval shape if plotted. [2d pic of ending points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t00cD.png) I found these transforms online that work. 
x' = x - (y + z)/2 , 
y' = y - (x + z)/2 , 
z' = z - (x + y)/2 , 
x'' = sqrt(3) * (y' - x')/2 , 
y'' = z' - (x' + y')/2 , 
Here is a picture of the transformed points [3d histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMKCW.png) What is the general math that explains the transformation of x,y,z points to x,y? I have only taken a "engineer" linear algebra course where I learned nothing, so maybe explain in layman terms. Thank you

Comment: What is it that you’d like explained: why the distribution of the endpoints is circularly symmetric or why the projection of a circle is an ellipse?

Comment: Sorry it is kind of ambiguous. How to transform the endpoints of the circular distribution to a xy plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number of steps is the same for all trajectories, endpoints lie on the plane $x+y+z=1000$:

[image]

Due to the initial symmetry, the distribution of endpoints on this plane is symmetric with regard of 120° rotations around vector $\vec e=(1,1,1)$ (permutation of axes $x,y,z$).

If you consider only $x,y$ coordinates of the endpoints, you will get a projections of this plane (and the distribution) onto $xy$ plane. In other words, you will get a shadow indeed.

You other transformation can be written as:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x''\\y''
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 -\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4} & \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4} & 0 \\
 -\frac{3}{4} & -\frac{3}{4} & \frac{3}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

If you consider two rows of the transformation matrix as vectors: $\vec u=\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}, \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}, 0\right)$, $\vec v=\left(-\frac{3}{4}, -\frac{3}{4}, \frac{3}{2}\right)$, you can notice that both of them are orthogonal to the normal of the plane $\vec e$:
$$\vec u\cdot\vec e = 0\qquad \text{and} \qquad\vec v\cdot\vec e = 0.$$
That means both of them lie on the plane. Moreover, they are orthogonal to each other: $\vec u\cdot\vec v=0$ and they lengths are equal $|\vec u|=|\vec v|$. That means this transformation doesn't skew the distribution unlike $xy$ projection.

However, this transformation scales the distribution, since $k=|\vec u|=|\vec v| = \sqrt{\frac{27}8}\approx 1.84$. So the distribution on your 3d histogram appear $k$ times wider that it would look like if we just took points on the plane. In order to fix this, you need to divide all the numbers in your final matrix by $k$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x'''\\y'''
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

And the distribution looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much this is everything I needed and more. Some parts I may have to research. What do you mean by 120 degree rotation around vector (1,1,1). My intuition told me that a normal vector to my circular distribution is (1,1,1). These matrix transformations, are the general or specific to my example? Do you know what i could look up to learn more. Thank you

Comment: The pictures you got are awesome, how did you get them?

Comment: When you permute axes as $x\to y\to z\to x$, it's the same as the rotation on 120° around the line $x=y=z$. These numbers in the matrices are specific to your example. But in general, any linear transformation can be seen as matrix multiplication. Look up Wikipedia on [linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Examples_of_linear_transformation_matrices) and [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projection). I made images in Wolfram Mathematica. It's good for such things, but quite expensive.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to look it up now. What is permute? This 120 degrees is an angle in reference to what, x =y = z? I feel an angle that big would put me in some negative coordinates. Wolfram seems nice, my pics took me forever in python.

Comment: Maybe [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bui0h.gif) will help.

Comment: Well maybe after I try to learn this stuff. Thank you again, I was truly stuck

Comment: Sorry one last question, how did you figure out the values for the correct matrix transformations?

Comment: I divided the components of $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ by their length $k$.

Comment: @ChrisBolig The transformation is basically a translation to the centroid of the distribution followed by a rotation that aligns the plane’s normal with the $z$-axis. This is followed by orthogonal projection onto the $x$-$y$ plane, which amounts to dropping the last coordinate and is accomplished by deleting the last row of the translation/rotation matrix.